# hash_hmac with sha1 in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hmacsha1

I have this in PHP:

```
$res = base64_encode( hash_hmac ("sha1", $stringToSign, $this->secretKey, true) );
```

In Node.js I tried:

```
var res = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secretKey).update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
```

Doesn't work. Don't get the same result - what do I do wrong?

Comment: Works for me, are you sure the key and string are exactly the same and don't contain any hidden characters or spaces? Examples[[php](http://3v4l.org/PRnI0),[node](http://runnable.com/me/U5A9j2zuRzd01mQv)]

Comment: thx, hidden character it was

Comment: Glad you've got your answer, ezmilhous! As the problem is not in the code, could you delete the question? It cannot be answered in the current form. Otherwise it will have to go through the close/delete queue.